# How to search for a specified number in a string as a whole

Tags: c#, string, substring, indexof

My english is not very good so forgive me. I want to search for a number in a string and get the next 1 character.Lets take the number 6 for example. When i search it, it finds the number 6 but it is part of the number 16. I want to find the number 6 as a whole not part of another number.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                int i2 = i + 1;
                answer = readTxt;
                answer = answer.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
              //  MessageBox.Show(answer);
                answer = answer.Substring(answer.IndexOf(i2 + ".") + 2, 1); //Search for number and get the text next to it

                //add answers to listbox
                listBox1.Items.Add(answer);
                string answrLetter = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
               }
```

I want to search for that number in the "answer" variable.The contents of the variable is huge so i wont put it in here

Comment: What do you mean as the "text next to it"? The next character? Maybe it would be great to provide an example. Are there more 6s in the text? If yes do you need all of them or just the first?

Comment: @szkup sorry i didnt explain it very well. I want to get the next 1 character. Yes there are more 6s in the text because there are numbers like 16,56,36

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the `string` with a for loop and check if the previous character is not a number with `Char.IsNumber` ([see documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isnumber?view=netframework-4.8).) To check if a character's numeric value equals with `i2` use `Char.GetNumericValue` ([see documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getnumericvalue?view=netframework-4.8).)

```
for (int j = 0; j < answer.Length - 1; j++)
{
    if ((j == 0 || !Char.IsNumber(answer, j - 1)) && Char.GetNumericValue(answer, j) == i2 && answer[j + 1] == '.')
        //you find i2 at position j, the previous character (if exists) is not a number, the next character is '.'
}
```